# How do I load a django template using absolute paths?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template xyz.html stored in the path /doc-templates/ so the full path is /doc-templates/xyz.html

I'm trying to load the template using

```
my_template = get_template('/doc-templates/xyz.html')
```

But this raises the TemplateDoesNotExist exception. Any ideas before I roll out my own template loader?
PS: Yes I know where Django templates should be, I just want to see if this is possible now that everything is being "dockerized"

I have explicitly enabled django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader and set the DIRS to a non empty list as documented but it seems to be ignoring the absolute path (possibly appending it to the DIRS list)

Comment: The duplicate question is different, I don't have a problem loading templates, just wanted to find out how to load templates that are not in my project path, which could be a different drive (windows) or a mount point out of the project BASE_DIR (a mounted docker volume) using absolute paths. eg if the project is in /app/myproj my templates are in /doc-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the template folder `doc-templates/` to your settings.py under templates `DIRS` as follows

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['doc-templates/'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
}
]
```

Then call your template by name `xyz.html`

P.S the path shall be relative to the `BASE_DIR`.

Comment: This worked, but with an absolute path /doc-templates - note that it is completely out of the project path.